# New Random in a For-Next-Statement Repeats the Same Value

Tags: vb.net, random

I am creating 3 random bytes in a for-next-statement.

However, they are always the same for each for-next, for example "333", or "777".

I wonder why this is so and what I am doing wrong.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim s As String = String.Empty

    For i As Integer = 0 To 2
        s += GetRandomByte().ToString
    Next

    Me.TextBox1.Text = s

End Sub

Public Function GetRandomByte(Optional ByVal uLow As Byte = 1, Optional ByVal uHigh As Byte = 9) As Byte

    Dim r As New Random
    Dim b As Integer = r.Next(CInt(uLow), CInt(uHigh + 1))

    Return b

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your constructor for the new Random, give it a new seed each time.  I like to use the current timestamp's hashcode value

```
New Random(Now.GetHashCode)
```

Comment: Better would be to declare the Random instance outside the method.

Answer (score 0):

keep same instance for all calls:

```
Dim r As New Random()

Public Function GetRandomByte(Optional ByVal uLow As Byte = 1, Optional ByVal uHigh As Byte = 9) As Byte
    Return r.Next(CInt(uLow), CInt(uHigh + 1))
End Function
```

or, pass to Random constructor a seed:

```
Dim r As New Random(CInt(Date.Now.Ticks And &h0000FFFF))
```